# Automapper DTO to Entity Framework Core model

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I'm building my first .NET Core 3.1 API, I have problem with properly map DTO to model, I'm sending JSON with userId of existing user:

```
{
   "userId": 0,
   "storageName": "string"
}
```

It throws an error that looks like it's trying to create new instead of map to existing user from database

> Backend_API_DEV | fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
> Backend_API_DEV |
> Failed executing DbCommand (43ms) [Parameters=[@p0='?' (DbType = Int32), @p1='?' (Size = 4000), @p2='?' (Size = 4000), @p3='?' (Size = 4000)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
> Backend_API_DEV |       SET NOCOUNT ON;
> Backend_API_DEV |       INSERT INTO [Users] ([UserId], [UserEmail], [UserName], [UserPassword])
> Backend_API_DEV |       VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3);
> Backend_API_DEV | fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
> Backend_API_DEV |       An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'Backend.Data.BackendContext'.

Other DTO's/models that I use don't have foreign keys and they map properly, so I can create and update objects in DB. I think my problem is with map configuration, but I don't know how to properly do it.

```
namespace Backend.Profiles
{
    public class StorageProfile : Profile
    {
        public StorageProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<StorageCreateDto, Storage>()
                .ForPath(dest => dest.IdUser.UserId, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.UserId));
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
namespace Backend.Models
{
    public class Storage
    {
        [Key]
        public int StorageId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual User IdUser { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string StorageName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
namespace Backend.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class StorageController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IBackendRepo _repository;
        private readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public StorageController(IBackendRepo repository, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _repository = repository;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<StorageReadDto> CreateStorage(StorageCreateDto storageCreateDto)
        {
            var model = _mapper.Map<Storage>(storageCreateDto);
            _repository.CreateStorage(model);
            _repository.SaveChanges();

            var readDto = _mapper.Map<StorageReadDto>(model);

            return CreatedAtRoute(nameof(GetStorageById), new { Id = readDto.StorageId }, readDto);
        }
    }
}
```

Repository that save changes to the database:

```
    public bool SaveChanges()
    {
        return (_context.SaveChanges() >= 0);
    }

    public void CreateStorage(Storage storage)
    {
        if (storage == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(storage));
        }

        _context.Storages.Add(storage);
    }
```

Comment: I think you should define a prop `UserId` which is the FK itself

Answer (score 0):

If `storage.User` is a non-null reference, then adding `storage` to context:

```
_context.Storages.Add(storage);
```

adds referenced `User` as well. This is how `DbSet<T>.Add` works - it adds the whole object graph.

There are two options:

1. Re-design `Storage` to add foreign key property `UserId`. When mapping DTO to storage, initialize foreign key property instead of reference property. That is, initialize user id instead of user. (Also, it's better to rename `IdUser` property, such name confuses, since this is not an identifier, but reference).
2. After adding `storage`, set the state of referenced user explicitly to `Unchanged`:

```
_context.Entry(storage.IdUser).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```